# No puedo extraer los datos del archivo json

Tags: javascript, json

Estoy aprendiendo a usar un archivo json en una solicitud XMLHttpRequest. El archivo json solamente tiene un objeto para asi poder probar si esta funcionando `{ "msip": 1060 };` es todo lo que tiene el fichero json. En el archivo html tengo este codigo.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function ajax_get_json_msip(){
        
            var resultados = document.getElementById("resultados");
            var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            
            hr.open("GET", "msip.json", true);
            hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);
            hr.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200){
                    var extensiones = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
                    resultados.innerHTML = extensiones;
                }
        }
        hr.send(null);
    }
        
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="resultados"></div>
    <script>ajax_get_json_msip();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Cuando abro la pagina no me sale nada. Se me hace que el error esta dentro de:

```
if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200){
                    var extensiones = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
                    resultados.innerHTML = extensiones;
                }
```

Segun yo en la variable `extensiones` se encuentra todos los datos del archivo json. Pero parece que asi no es.

Comment: Puedes hacer un `console.dir(extensiones)` para ver que te arroja. No uses `console.log()`, usa [`console.dir()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Console/dir).

Comment: ```Uncaught ReferenceError: extensiones is not defined
    at ajax_get_json_msip (json.html:19)
    at json.html:26
json.html:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; in JSON at position 16
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.hr.onreadystatechange (json.html:14)```

Comment: Revisa el fichero `json`. Tienes un carácter inválido, por lo visto un `;`. Puedes validar el contenido de tu fichero en [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/). Saludos

Comment: Ya le quite el ```;``` y me salio otro mensaje que dice lo siguiente ```Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/wamp64/www/sistemacapa/msip.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.```